# Enviar imagen atraves de Http Post

Tags: java, nodejs, webservice, meteor

Hola a todos intento enviar un archivo de node(Cliente) a mi web service (Servidor) de Java usando [Jersey](https://jersey.github.io/download.html) el archivo se recibe de manera correcta usando [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/) este es mi codigo Java:

```
@POST
@Path("eliminar")
@Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, ("text/plain") })
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response eliminar(
        @FormDataParam("attachment") InputStream fileInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("attachment") FormDataContentDisposition cdh){
        try{
            if(fileInputStream==null){
             System.out.println("Nulo");    
            }else{                  
                 saveFile(fileInputStream, "C://logs/"+ObjectId.get().toString()+".png");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("Catch "+e.getMessage());                                       
        }
    return Response.ok().entity("Eliminar").build();
}

private void saveFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,String serverLocation) {
    try {
        System.out.println(serverLocation);
        OutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        outpuStream.flush();
        outpuStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

En esta parte solo muevo el archivo que recibo a otra carpeta, para revisar que se ha recibido de manera correcta.

> Codigo Node:

```
conImagen: function() {
  var bitmap = fs.readFileSync("C:/Users/obar/Desktop/prueba.png"); // Intento subir este archivo como muestra
  var valor= new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64'); // genero el buffer para enviarlo por Post
  var parts = {
    attachment: {
      contentType: 'image/png',
      filename: 'prueba.png',
      value:valor,
    }
  };
  var formData = MultipartFormData(parts);
  HTTP.call(
    'POST',
    'http://localhost:8080/restdemo/jaxrs/customers/eliminar', {
      content: formData.content,
      headers: formData.headers
    },
    function(error, result) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error, 'Error');
      }
      if (result) {
        var statusCode=result.statusCode;
        var content=result.content;
        console.log("result "+content);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Mi funcion Multipart es:

```
MultipartFormData=function(parts) {
var boundary = '----' + (new Date()).getTime();
var bodyString = [];
_.each(parts, function(value, name, blah) {
  console.log("value "+JSON.stringify(value)+" name "+name);
  if (name === 'attachment') {
    bodyString.push(
      '--' + boundary,
      'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' + name + '";' +
      'filename="' + value.filename + '"',
      'Content-type: ' + value.contentType,
      '',
      value.value);
  } else {
    bodyString.push(
      '--' + boundary,
      'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' + name + '"',
      '',
      value);
  }
});
bodyString.push('--' + boundary + '--', '');
return {
  content: bodyString.join('\r\n'),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;boundary=' + boundary
  }
}
}
```

El archivo se recibe pero de manera corrupta.

Comment: Consulta que es lo que tratas hacer aqui `"C://logs/"+ObjectId.get().toString()+".png"`

Comment: ¿Estás subiendo el fichero en formato base64?

Comment: @RaulCacacho solo le pongo un nombre unico autogenerado al archivo

Comment: @PabloLozano si asi es subo el archivo como base64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el problema es que estás subiendo el fichero tras transformar su contenido a Base64, pero en el lado del servidor no lo decodificas, sino que lo guardas tal cual, con lo que tendrás un fichero que ocupa más que el original y que si lo abres con un editor de texto podrás ver que sólo tiene letras y números.

Opciones:

- súbelo directamente en formato binario (usando un FormData, seguramente es lo que estás haciendo con Postman)
- Pasa de Base64 a binario en el servidor.

Comment: Mucha gracias por tu respuesta ha sido de gran ayuda segui tu segunda opción y cambie el codigo de mi servidor recibiendo un string en java y lo converti a base 64 y funciono =)

Comment: Yo hubiese usando la primera opción porque en Base64 requieres más bytes, pero un archivo PNG no debería ser muy pesado en cualquier caso. ¡Un placer ser de ayuda!